# OpenCV Python find contour point closest to a given point

Tags: python, opencv, distance, contour, opencv3.0

In OpenCV, for a given point `(x,y)`, what is the best way to find the point closest to it that belongs to a known contour `cnt`? (I assume the point lies outside the contour.)

```
dist = cv2.pointPolygonTest(cnt,(x,y),True)
```

pointPolygonTest returns the distance of the closest contour point but I do not see a way to get to the actual point.

Of course, I could loop over the list of contour points and recalculate the distance finding the one with minimum distance. (A couple of questions on SO explain more sophisticated ways for finding the closest point out of a list of points to a given point.)

Alternatively, I could draw a circle with radius `dist` and see where the circle and the contour touch.

Both options seem a little clunky, so I wonder if I am missing something more straight forward.

Comment: Unless the contour has known geometric properties, like a rectangle or a circle, you need to check each point and keep nearest.

Comment: Thanks! The contour is irregular. I just thought that pointPolygonTest must already know about the point I am looking for since it is calculating the distance.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/28210. This can help you

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Will do something like this if I really have to recalculate the distances.

Comment: @ikkjo The following answer is based on the post in the comment above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72109163/how-to-find-nearest-points-between-two-contours-in-opencv/72112157#72112157